# Changing a variable based off of window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

For some reason my if statement is refusing to fire even when my console.logged screen height is below the specified level. Here's my code:

```
var chartHeight = 290
var minPercentage = 5
var myHeight = window.innerHeight
console.log(myHeight)
if (myHeight < 800) {
    console.log('ding')
    chartHeight = 260
    minPercentage = 10
} else if (myHeight > 980) {
    chartHeight = 320
}
```

The console logs the height just fine, and I know that it's for sure a number. Any ideas as to what's going wrong here?

edit: I'm loading the page into chrome with the ipad emulator running (in dev tools) - I'm assuming that's the issue?

Comment: are you loading the page up/running the code at the lesser height? This works fine for me. To verify turn it into a function and invoke it on resize

Comment: The code works for me.

Comment: You probably want to put that code in a resize event handler. If you load page when it's large, you won't log the ding.